# How to make ASP.NET application always running on linux?

Tags: linux, asp.net-core, hangfire

We have a background job that is long running and cannot be idempotent. When redhat restarts our hangfire .net core app, we lose hours of progress.

We are using following configuration.

```
[Unit]
Description=ABC

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/html/ABC
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /var/www/html/ABC/XYZ.DLL
Restart=always

Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
Environment=DOTNET_PRINT_TELEMETRY_MESSAGE=false

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: `cron` + `curl` ?

Comment: _"When redhat restarts our hangfire .net core app, we lose hours of progress"_  - that indicates a design-flaw with your program - for starters, _you should always expect_ any webserver-based application-host to be arbitrarily restarted without warning at any time. If you need a reliable and uninterruptable execution environment then you should port your workflow to a daemon process - and make it fault-tolerant. For example, why can't you make "savepoints" saved to-disk over time so you don't have to start-over?

Comment: I suggest to implement partial commits in your very long running job. Eventually try to decompose it in smaller jobs. Have a look at Continuations Jobs: https://www.hangfire.io/